# cakephpでスラッシュで終わるリンクを生成する方法

Tags: php, cakephp

スラッシュで終わるリンクを生成したいのですが、今回パラメータを追加する必要があり、やり方がわかりません。

```
Router::url([
    'controller' => 'controller',
    'action'     => 'action',
    '?'          => ['id' => 1],
]);

// 結果
/controller/action?id=1

// こうしたい
/controller/action/?id=1
```

Comment: さんがお使いの CakePHP のバージョンと、web サーバ名(他環境等)があったほうが親切かもしれません。Trail Shash のやり方は CakePHP 1.x と CakePHP 2.x ではやり方が変わってくると思いますので。

Comment: [本家SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270633/remove-or-add-trailing-slash-from-cakephp-2-x-on-apache-using-htaccess)にスラッシュで終わる URL の設定方法があります。パッと見た感じ GET パラメータを付けた場合については言及されていませんが…。